# Адаптировать сортировку одномерных массивов под двумерные

Tags: алгоритм, pascal, сортировка

Есть программа на Паскале, которая занимается сортировкой Шелла и вставками. Процедуры сортировки замечательные и вроде как адекватно работают (если не ошибаюсь), но только с одномерными массивами (в данном случае тип `LittleDataArray`). Нужно адаптировать их под работу с двумерными массивами (в данном случае тип `LittleDataArray`).

Вот алгоритмы:

```
...
    DataItem = char;
    LittleDataArray = array [1..80] of char;
    DataArray = array [1..80,1..80] of char;
...
procedure Shell(var item: LittleDataArray);
var
i, j, k: integer;
   h: DataItem;
 begin
 amnt_s:=0;
   k := t shr 1;
  while k > 0 do
   begin
     for i := 0 to t - k do
     begin
       j := i;
       while (j >= 0) and (item[j] > item[j + k]) do
       begin
         h := item[j];
         item[j] := item[j + k]; inc(amnt_s);
         item[j + k] := h; inc(amnt_s);
         if j > k then
           Dec(j, k)
         else
           j := 0;
       end;
    end;
    k := k shr 1;
  end;
```

end;

procedure Inser(var item: LittleDataArray);
    var
        i, l, j: integer;
        x: DataItem;
        begin
        amnt_i:=0;
        for i := 2 to t do
    begin
            x := item[i]; inc(amnt_i);
            j := i-1;
            while (x0) do
            begin
             item[j+1] := item[j]; inc(amnt_i);
                 j := j-1;
            end;
            item[j+1] := x; inc(amnt_i);
        end;
end; { end Inser sort }

Comment: Ребят, а что делает функция "Сделать общим" для вопроса на данном портале?

Comment: Это означает, что вопрос превращается в свого рода вики-запись, т.е. каждый (ну у кого кармы хватит) может добавить в него что-то свое при желании.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже все. Решил сам. С двухмерного массива сделал большой одномерный, отсортировал его и трансформировал обратно. Мб такой метод не есть рациональным с точки зрения оптимизации, но для поставленного ТЗ это не имеет значения.

```
...
    DataItem = char;
    DataArray = array [1..maxLenght,1..maxLenght] of DataItem;
    BigDataArray = array [1..maxLengthDbl] of DataItem;
...
procedure Shell(var toSort: DataArray);
var
    k,itemLenght,p: integer;
    h: DataItem;
    item: BigDataArray;
begin
    amnt_s:=0;
    p:=1;
    for t2:=1 to t do
        for t3:=1 to t do
        begin
            item[p]:=toSort[t2,t3];
            p:=p+1;
        end;
    itemLenght:=t*t;
    k := itemLenght shr 1;
    while k > 0 do
    begin
        for t2 := 0 to itemLenght - k do
        begin
            t3 := t2;
            while (t3 >= 0) and (item[t3] > item[t3 + k]) do
            begin
                h := item[t3];
                item[t3] := item[t3 + k];
                item[t3 + k] := h;
                inc(amnt_s);
                if t3 > k then
                    Dec(t3, k)
                else
                    t3 := 0;
            end;
        end;
        k := k shr 1;
    end;
p:=1;
for t2:=1 to t do
    for t3:=1 to t do
    begin
        toSort[t2,t3]:=item[p];
        p:=p+1;
    end;

end;
procedure Inser(var toSort: DataArray);
var
    l, itemLenght, p: integer;
    x: DataItem;
    item: BigDataArray;
begin
    amnt_i:=0;
    p:=1;
    for t2:=1 to t do
        for t3:=1 to t do
        begin
            item[p]:=toSort[t2,t3];
            p:=p+1;
        end;
itemLenght:=t*t;
for t2 := 2 to itemLenght do
begin
    x := item[t2];
    t3 := t2-1;
    while (x<item[t3]) and (t3>0) do
    begin
        item[t3+1] := item[t3];
        inc(amnt_i);
        t3 := t3-1;
    end;
    item[t3+1] := x;
end;

p:=1;
for t2:=1 to t do
    for t3:=1 to t do
    begin
        toSort[t2,t3]:=item[p];
        p:=p+1;
    end;

end;
```

Comment: На Си программа была бы существенно короче :-)
Т.к. двумерных массивов в оперативной памяти не существует. Все равно он реализуется как одномерный массив. При этом индексы меняются по следующей схеме
<pre>    char a[MAX_X][MAX_Y];
    char *b = a;
    // обращаемся к элементу a[i][j];
    b[i*MAX_Y+j] = 0;    </pre>
В паскале тоже есть работа с указателями, но ничего хорошего с этого не выйдет.

Answer (score 0):

И как представляется алгоритм сортировки двумерного массива? По крайней мере скажите в каком порядке должны быть элементы, когда массив отсортирован.

Comment: Сортировка по-возрастанию. Параметр сортировки -  позиция символа в ASCII таблице.